# "Waiting for table flush" Against Analyze Command

Tags: mysql, database-locking

I was trying to run analyze command on a table out of 900 tables in **mysql 5.7.30**. Its stuck my all db process-list and connections spike immediate and lot of commands found with state **"Waiting for table flush"** even our max_connection parameter reaches at 2500. We are running the analyze table command from last 3 years but from last 1 month we notice this issue 4th time. If we didn't analyze our tables then we see severe performance issues and lot of queries enter into state "statistics".  Whats your thoughts on it

Comment: What do you gain from `ANALYZE`?  It sound like `OPTIMIZE` table, which should _not_ be used on InnoDB.

Comment: Tables don't have performance issues, queries do.  Let's see one of the slow queries (and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`) there may be a simple way to speed it up.

Comment: when we analyze table regularly then mostly our queries run perfectly. Its very common practice in DB optimization.

Comment: Do they eventually stop running perfectly?  (Other vendors may need this form of maintenance more than MySQL.)